# How to unzip a zip folder using php code

Tags: php, zip, unzip

I want to unzip directorires.

That means i have a zipped directory name with `xxx.zip`.In manuall i right clicked on the zipped directory and do extract folder,then i got an unzipped dirtectory with name `xxx` and also in this directory have a same directory `xxx`.In the subfolder will contained the files.

That means, xxx->xxx->files this is the heirarchi of unzipped folder.

So in my site i want to unzipp a directory using php code.

How can i do this? I need only `xxx->files` not `xxx->xxx->files` structure.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<?php
$zip = zip_open("zip.zip");
if ($zip) {
  while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
    $fp = fopen("zip/".zip_entry_name($zip_entry), "w");
    if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry, "r")) {
      $buf = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
      fwrite($fp,"$buf");
      zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
      fclose($fp);
    }
  }
  zip_close($zip);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 11):

See this http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('E:\pathto\zip\ashok_subedi.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('E:\pathto\extrac\myzip');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can upload this file to your web-server and run it. It will ask you to choose a zip file for unzipping, and you could specify the path where you want to unzip. In case you want to unzip the file in the current location, just leave the unzip path blank. On finishing the unzipping, it will give you feedback, too.

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ERROR);
//error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Quick Installer</title>
<style type="text/css">
/* Unzip v.1.0.1   23.11.2011 */
body, td {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #4e4e4e;
    background:#fff;
    text-align:center;
}
.wrapper {
    text-align:left;
    background:#f4f6f5;
    padding:0px 0 20px;
    width:700px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin:30px auto;
}
.wrap {
    background:#ea433b;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
}
.submit {
    border-top:1px solid #dbdbdb;
    padding-top:15px;
}
.submit input {
    margin-left:244px;
}
.indent {
    padding:16px 25px;
    border-top:3px solid #dfe1e0
}
.sect {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width:100%;
}
.label {
    width:234px;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    line-height:42px;
    text-indent:100px
}
.field {
    width:350px;
    float:left;
}
.field span {
    font-size:10px
}
.css3button {
    cursor:pointer;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(  top,  #54cbe9 0%,  #3790cf);
    background: -webkit-gradient(  linear, left top, left bottom,  from(#54cbe9),  to(#3790cf));
    border-radius: 18px;
    -moz-border-radius: 18px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow:
 0px 0px 0px rgba(000, 000, 000, 0),  inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow:
 0px 0px 0px rgba(000, 000, 000, 0),  inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    text-shadow:
 1px 1px 0px rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.4),  0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    background:#54cbe9\9;
}
.css3input {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width:307px
}
.p3 {
    padding:7px;
}
a {
    color: #000066;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #FF6600;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.form_indent {
    padding-left:210px;
}
.small {
    font:normal 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}
h1 {
    background:#ea433b;
    border-bottom:1px solid #be382f;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    text-indent:116px;
    color:#fff;
    font:bold 36px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height:64px;
    margin:0;
    text-shadow:
 1px 2px 2px rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.4),  1px 2px 2px rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.3);
}
h1 div {
    border-bottom:1px solid #d23d36;
}
h1 div div {
    border-bottom:1px solid #e24137;
    height:64px;
}
.file_upload {
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php // print_r ($_SERVER); ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1><div><div>Quick Installer</div></div></h1>
    <div class="indent">
        <form name="myform" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return check_uploadObject(this);">
            <?php
    if(!$_REQUEST["myaction"]):
?>
            <div class="sect">
                <div class="label"> Choose your zip file: </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <select name="zipfile" class="css3input">
                        <option value="" selected>- Please choose -</option>
                        <?php
                        $fdir = opendir('./');
                        while($file=readdir($fdir)){
                            if(!is_file($file)) continue;
                            if(preg_match('/\.zip$/mis',$file)){
                                echo "<option value='$file'>$file</option>\r\n";
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sect">
                <div class="label"> Unzip to: </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <input name="todir" type="text" id="todir" value="" size="15" class="css3input">
                    <br>
                    <span>(Leave this field blank if you want to unzip into a current directory. Folder should be writable - 755 permissions)</span> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sect submit">
                <input name="myaction" type="hidden" id="myaction" value="dounzip">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="css3button" value="Unzip">
            </div>
            <?php

elseif($_REQUEST["myaction"]=="dounzip"):

class zip
{

 var $total_files = 0;
 var $total_folders = 0; 

 function Extract ( $zn, $to, $index = Array(-1) )
 {
   $ok = 0; $zip = @fopen($zn,'rb');
   if(!$zip) return(-1);
   $cdir = $this->ReadCentralDir($zip,$zn);
   $pos_entry = $cdir['offset'];

   if(!is_array($index)){ $index = array($index);  }
   for($i=0; $index[$i];$i++){
        if(intval($index[$i])!=$index[$i]||$index[$i]>$cdir['entries'])
        return(-1);
   }
   for ($i=0; $i<$cdir['entries']; $i++)
   {
     @fseek($zip, $pos_entry);
     $header = $this->ReadCentralFileHeaders($zip);
     $header['index'] = $i; $pos_entry = ftell($zip);
     @rewind($zip); fseek($zip, $header['offset']);
     if(in_array("-1",$index)||in_array($i,$index))
        $stat[$header['filename']]=$this->ExtractFile($header, $to, $zip);
   }
   fclose($zip);
   return $stat;
 }

  function ReadFileHeader($zip)
  {
    $binary_data = fread($zip, 30);
    $data = unpack('vchk/vid/vversion/vflag/vcompression/vmtime/vmdate/Vcrc/Vcompressed_size/Vsize/vfilename_len/vextra_len', $binary_data);

    $header['filename'] = fread($zip, $data['filename_len']);
    if ($data['extra_len'] != 0) {
      $header['extra'] = fread($zip, $data['extra_len']);
    } else { $header['extra'] = ''; }

    $header['compression'] = $data['compression'];$header['size'] = $data['size'];
    $header['compressed_size'] = $data['compressed_size'];
    $header['crc'] = $data['crc']; $header['flag'] = $data['flag'];
    $header['mdate'] = $data['mdate'];$header['mtime'] = $data['mtime'];

    if ($header['mdate'] && $header['mtime']){
     $hour=($header['mtime']&0xF800)>>11;$minute=($header['mtime']&0x07E0)>>5;
     $seconde=($header['mtime']&0x001F)*2;$year=(($header['mdate']&0xFE00)>>9)+1980;
     $month=($header['mdate']&0x01E0)>>5;$day=$header['mdate']&0x001F;
     $header['mtime'] = mktime($hour, $minute, $seconde, $month, $day, $year);
    }else{$header['mtime'] = time();}

    $header['stored_filename'] = $header['filename'];
    $header['status'] = "ok";
    return $header;
  }

 function ReadCentralFileHeaders($zip){
    $binary_data = fread($zip, 46);
    $header = unpack('vchkid/vid/vversion/vversion_extracted/vflag/vcompression/vmtime/vmdate/Vcrc/Vcompressed_size/Vsize/vfilename_len/vextra_len/vcomment_len/vdisk/vinternal/Vexternal/Voffset', $binary_data);

    if ($header['filename_len'] != 0)
      $header['filename'] = fread($zip,$header['filename_len']);
    else $header['filename'] = '';

    if ($header['extra_len'] != 0)
      $header['extra'] = fread($zip, $header['extra_len']);
    else $header['extra'] = '';

    if ($header['comment_len'] != 0)
      $header['comment'] = fread($zip, $header['comment_len']);
    else $header['comment'] = '';

    if ($header['mdate'] && $header['mtime'])
    {
      $hour = ($header['mtime'] & 0xF800) >> 11;
      $minute = ($header['mtime'] & 0x07E0) >> 5;
      $seconde = ($header['mtime'] & 0x001F)*2;
      $year = (($header['mdate'] & 0xFE00) >> 9) + 1980;
      $month = ($header['mdate'] & 0x01E0) >> 5;
      $day = $header['mdate'] & 0x001F;
      $header['mtime'] = mktime($hour, $minute, $seconde, $month, $day, $year);
    } else {
      $header['mtime'] = time();
    }
    $header['stored_filename'] = $header['filename'];
    $header['status'] = 'ok';
    if (substr($header['filename'], -1) == '/')
      $header['external'] = 0x41FF0010;
    return $header;
 }

 function ReadCentralDir($zip,$zip_name){
    $size = filesize($zip_name);

    if ($size < 277) $maximum_size = $size;
    else $maximum_size=277;

    @fseek($zip, $size-$maximum_size);
    $pos = ftell($zip); $bytes = 0x00000000;

    while ($pos < $size){
        $byte = @fread($zip, 1); $bytes=($bytes << 8) | ord($byte);
        if ($bytes == 0x504b0506 or $bytes == 0x2e706870504b0506){ $pos++;break;} $pos++;
    }

    $fdata=fread($zip,18);

    $data=@unpack('vdisk/vdisk_start/vdisk_entries/ventries/Vsize/Voffset/vcomment_size',$fdata);

    if ($data['comment_size'] != 0) $centd['comment'] = fread($zip, $data['comment_size']);
    else $centd['comment'] = ''; $centd['entries'] = $data['entries'];
    $centd['disk_entries'] = $data['disk_entries'];
    $centd['offset'] = $data['offset'];$centd['disk_start'] = $data['disk_start'];
    $centd['size'] = $data['size'];  $centd['disk'] = $data['disk'];
    return $centd;
  }

 function ExtractFile($header,$to,$zip){
    $header = $this->readfileheader($zip);

    if(substr($to,-1)!="/") $to.="/";
    if($to=='./') $to = ''; 
    $pth = explode("/",$to.$header['filename']);
    $mydir = '';
    for($i=0;$i<count($pth)-1;$i++){
        if(!$pth[$i]) continue;
        $mydir .= $pth[$i]."/";
        if((!is_dir($mydir) && @mkdir($mydir,0777)) || (($mydir==$to.$header['filename'] || ($mydir==$to && $this->total_folders==0)) && is_dir($mydir)) ){
            @chmod($mydir,0777);
            $this->total_folders ++;
            echo "<input name='dfile[]' type='checkbox' value='$mydir' checked> <a href='$mydir' target='_blank'><strong>Directory: $mydir</strong></a><br>";
        }
    }

    if(strrchr($header['filename'],'/')=='/') return;   

    if (!($header['external']==0x41FF0010)&&!($header['external']==16)){
        if ($header['compression']==0){
            $fp = @fopen($to.$header['filename'], 'wb');
            if(!$fp) return(-1);
            $size = $header['compressed_size'];

            while ($size != 0){
                $read_size = ($size < 2048 ? $size : 2048);
                $buffer = fread($zip, $read_size);
                $binary_data = pack('a'.$read_size, $buffer);
                @fwrite($fp, $binary_data, $read_size);
                $size -= $read_size;
            }
            fclose($fp);
            touch($to.$header['filename'], $header['mtime']);
        }else{
            $fp = @fopen($to.$header['filename'].'.gz','wb');
            if(!$fp) return(-1);
            $binary_data = pack('va1a1Va1a1', 0x8b1f, Chr($header['compression']),
            Chr(0x00), time(), Chr(0x00), Chr(3));

            fwrite($fp, $binary_data, 10);
            $size = $header['compressed_size'];

            while ($size != 0){
                $read_size = ($size < 1024 ? $size : 1024);
                $buffer = fread($zip, $read_size);
                $binary_data = pack('a'.$read_size, $buffer);
                @fwrite($fp, $binary_data, $read_size);
                $size -= $read_size;
            }

            $binary_data = pack('VV', $header['crc'], $header['size']);
            fwrite($fp, $binary_data,8); fclose($fp);

            $gzp = @gzopen($to.$header['filename'].'.gz','rb') or die("Failed to create directory");
            if(!$gzp) return(-2);
            $fp = @fopen($to.$header['filename'],'wb');
            if(!$fp) return(-1);
            $size = $header['size'];

            while ($size != 0){
                $read_size = ($size < 2048 ? $size : 2048);
                $buffer = gzread($gzp, $read_size);
                $binary_data = pack('a'.$read_size, $buffer);
                @fwrite($fp, $binary_data, $read_size);
                $size -= $read_size;
            }
            fclose($fp); gzclose($gzp);

            touch($to.$header['filename'], $header['mtime']);
            @unlink($to.$header['filename'].'.gz');

        }
    }

    $this->total_files ++;
    echo "<input name='dfile[]' type='checkbox' value='$to$header[filename]' checked> <a href='$to$header[filename]' target='_blank'>Files: $to$header[filename]</a><br>";

    return true;
 }

// end class
}

    set_time_limit(0);

    if(!$_POST["todir"]) $_POST["todir"] = ".";
    $z = new Zip;
    $have_zip_file = 0;
    function start_unzip($tmp_name,$new_name,$checked){
        global $_POST,$z,$have_zip_file;
        $upfile = array("tmp_name"=>$tmp_name,"name"=>$new_name);
        if(is_file($upfile["tmp_name"])){
            $have_zip_file = 1;
            echo "<br><div class='wrap'>In Process: <input name='dfile[]' type='checkbox' value='$upfile[name]' ".($checked?"checked":"")."> $upfile[name]</div><br><br>";
            if(preg_match('/\.zip$/mis',$upfile["name"])){
                $result=$z->Extract($upfile["tmp_name"],$_POST["todir"]);
                if($result==-1){
                    echo "<br>File $upfile[name] error.<br>";
                }
                echo "<br>Done, Create $z->total_folders directory(s), $z->total_files file(s).<br><br><br>";
            }else{
                echo "<br>$upfile[name] is not a zip file.<br><br>";            
            }
            if(realpath($upfile["name"])!=realpath($upfile["tmp_name"])){
                @unlink($upfile["name"]);
                rename($upfile["tmp_name"],$upfile["name"]);
            }
        }
    }
    clearstatcache();

    start_unzip($_POST["zipfile"],$_POST["zipfile"],0);
    start_unzip($_FILES["upfile"]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["upfile"]["name"],1);

    if(!$have_zip_file){
        echo "<br>Please select or upload files.<br>";
    }
?>
            <input name="myaction" type="hidden" id="myaction" value="dodelete">
            <input name="button" type="button" class="css3button" value="go back" onClick="window.location='<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>';">
            <input type='button' class="css3button" value='Inverse' onclick='selrev();'>
            <input type='submit' class="css3button" onclick='return confirm("Delete the selected file?");' value='Delete the selected file'>
            <script language='javascript'>
function selrev() {
    with(document.myform) {
        for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
            thiselm = elements[i];
            if(thiselm.name.match(/dfile\[]/))  thiselm.checked = !thiselm.checked;
        }
    }
}
alert('Completed.');
</script>
            <?php

elseif($_REQUEST["myaction"]=="dodelete"):
    set_time_limit(0);

    $dfile = $_POST["dfile"]; 
    echo "Deleting files...<br><br>";
    if(is_array($dfile)){
        for($i=count($dfile)-1;$i>=0;$i--){
            if(is_file($dfile[$i])){
                if(@unlink($dfile[$i])){
                    echo "Deleted files: $dfile[$i]<br>";
                }else{
                    echo "Delete file failed: $dfile[$i]<br>";
                }
            }else{
                if(@rmdir($dfile[$i])){
                    echo "<strong>Deleted directory: $dfile[$i]</strong><br>";
                }else{
                    echo "<strong>Failed to delete directory: $dfile[$i]</strong><br>";
                }               
            }

        }
    }
    echo "<br>Completed.<br><br><input type='button' value='go back' class='css3button' onclick=\"window.location='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]';\"><br><br>
         <script language='javascript'>('Completed.');</script>";

endif;
?>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```